# how to fix this file stream warning?

Tags: c++

I come from Java and I don't know why my C++ compiler is giving me a warning.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class File {

public:
    File();
    File(const File& orig);
    virtual ~File();
    void leggi();


private:
    fstream file;
};
```

If I want to associate the reference to a new object, I do this:

```
void File::leggi() {
    file = fstream("file.txt", fstream::in);
    if (!file) {
        cout << "create file before!";
        return;
    }
    file.close();
    return;
}
```

> File.cpp:30:10: note: implicit copy assignment operator for 'std::__1::basic_fstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' first required here"

What can I do?

Comment: You can't copy stream objects. Change `file = fstream("file.txt", fstream::in);` to `file.open("file.txt", fstream::in);`

Comment: What @πάνταῥεῖ said, or compile in C++11 (or newer) settings, the necessary operations were added since then.